# useState doesn't work properly used few times in function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have simple function:

```
const payForCheckedOrders = () => {await realizePayment()};

const Test = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);

   console.log('render', counter, counter2);

    const realizePayment = async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          console.log('func start', counter, counter2);
          setCounter(counter + 1);
          setCounter2(prev => prev + 1);
          console.log('func end', counter, counter2);
         await sleep(500);
        }
    };
}
```

Important fact is when I call function, results are:

*func start 0 0*

*func end 0 0*

*render 1 1*

*func start 0 0*

*render 1 1*

*render 1 2*

*func end 0 0*

*func start 0 0*

*render 1 2*

*render 1 3*

*func end 0 0*

My question is why **counter** hasn't got same value as **counter2** in render console log.

And why reading state from inside function, even after changing state, console log showing initial value?

I thought it's async/await problem, but it's not. I've done almost the same synchronous and result was the same.

Comment: You are not supposed to use the `useState` that way, it should be used in combination with the `useEffect` hook. Since `useState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous, you need to "listen" for changes on those variable using `useEffect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that each time the component renders, the current values of `counter` and `counter2` are read, and these values will not change until the component renders again.  So the first time the component renders, both `counter` and `counter2` will be `0`.

Similarly, a new copy of `realizePayment` is created, which holds onto particular versions of `counter` and `counter2`, via closure.  So the first render's version of `realizePayment`, `counter` and `counter2` are also still 0, regardless of how many times its called.

1. Why does `counter2` increment when `counter` doesn't?

Because `counter` is set with `setCounter(counter + 1)` while `counter2` is set with `setCounter2(prev => prev + 1)`: since the `counter` variable doesn't change, `counter + 1` is always the same, for a given version of `realizePayment`.  For the first render's version, `counter` is 0, so it's doing `setCounter(1)` multiple times.  (Hence why it's always `1` in subsequent renders).

On the other hand the `prev => prev + 1` version used by `setCounter2` reads the current value, rather than relying on the `counter2` variable, which does not change.

2. Why do they log the same things at the end of the function as at the beginning?

Again, neither variable ever changes for a given version of `realizePayment`, so they will always log the same values at the end of the function as the beginning.

3. Why are they always 0 at the beginning of `realizePayment` even after the state has been updated?

Your example code is very unclear as to how `realizePayment` is being called: as written, it's not legal JS, you're calling a function defined inside a component from outside the component.

But remember that each render of the component produces a new copy of the `realizePayment` function, with specific values for `counter` and `counter2`.  Based on your logs, you're always calling the same version of `realizePayment`, the one from the initial render.